# W3C Duplicate ID...but I have to have two ids

Tags: jquery, html

I have two hyperlinks in my page that link to the same jquery popup tab, but both use the same Id. With w3C validator, it is giving me an error that I have to use unique IDs. I know that I cannot use the same ID twice, but what can I do if I have to link to the same popup tab twice on the same page?

```
<a href="/register" class="open-popup-link" id="register-link">Register</a>
 <a href="/register" class="open-popup-link" id="register-link">Join now!</a>
```

Does anyone have a better solution? Can I link an href to the original href, this way I have one ID in the page?

Comment: Move the `id` as a `class` and attach event listener to `a` with that `class`

Comment: @Jeff Puckett II can you explain more in code, I am still a rookie. do you mean make it like this ? <a href="/register" class="open-popup-link register-link">Register</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `id` to a `class` and attach event listener to `a` with that `class`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.swip.codylindley.com/jquery.popupWindow.js"></script>

<a href="http://example.com" class="open-popup-link register-link">Register</a>
<a href="http://example.com" class="open-popup-link register-link">Join now!</a>

<script>
$(".register-link").popupWindow({
  height:500,
  width:800,
  top:50,
  left:50
});
</script>
```